# npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10 2

Tags: cordova, npm

**Hi guys**

[This screen describes my whole problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4JRB.png)

Please help

Some days I can not handle it

i used win10

Thx

Comment: Somewhere - in one of `cordova`'s dependencies - there is a module that depends upon a now-deprecated version of `minimatch`. Beyond tracking down the module and petitioning its author to update said dependency, there's nothing you can really do about it. It's a warning; ignore it.

Comment: Can you help with the name of the module?

Comment: With `cordova` installed, you can get the full `node_modules` hierarchy with this command: `npm list`. That should show the entire tree - including the versions. Search for the `minimatch` version and you should find the offending module. Addressing this is up to the module author, as there could be breaking changes in `minimatch`, etc.

Comment: Hello, StackOverflow is not only for helping you but helping having same problem too. Could you please post the text and not screenshots ? Thanks.